# Simple question about extending of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be $n$-dimensional manifold, $p \in M$, $V$- open neighbourhood of $p$ and let $Y$ be a smooth vector field in $V$.

Do there exist an open neighbourhood
$W \subset V$ of $p$ and a smooth vector field $X$ on the whole $M$ which  extends $Y|_W$ ? How to do it. I know that similar fact, but for smooth real valued functions instead of smooth vector fields, holds.

Thanks.

Comment: [A related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/119415/5363), the answer of which you should be able to adapt to the present setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p \in K \subset W \subset V$, where $K$ compact, $W$ open, let
$\phi :W \rightarrow R^n$  be a chart, and let
$Y(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i (x) \partial|_i(x) $ for $x \in W$.
There exists $\chi \in C_c^\infty$  such that $\chi|_K=1$, $supp(\chi)\subset W$.

Put $X(x):=\chi(x) Y_i(x) \partial|_i(x)$ for $x \in W$ and $X(x)=0$ for $x \in M\setminus W$.

Then $X$ is smooth on $M$ and $X|_W=Y$.