# Homogeneity of a geodesic (Lemma 2.2, P64 Do Carmo, Riemannian Geometry)

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

[image]

[Definition of covariant derivative of vector fields along a curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI4ww.png)

I don't really understand the red line.
For sure, to ensure $\frac{D}{d t}\left(\frac{d h}{d t}\right)=\nabla_{h^{\prime}(t)} h^{\prime}(t)$, $h^{\prime}(t)$ should be induced from a vector field $Y \in \mathcal{X}(M)$, i.e.,
$$h'(t)=Y(h(t)).$$
I think, that is why the $h'(t)$ is extended to a neighborhood of $h(t)$ in $M$. (by bump function, it could be a smooth vector field on $M$.)
But how can $h'(t)$ be extended to a neighborhood of $h(t)$ in $M$?
Since $h'(t)$ is a vector field along a curve, how could we smoothly extend a field along a curve to an open subset?

Answer (score 1):

The question is local, so we can assume that the geodesic $\gamma=\{h(t)\vert t\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\}$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$. The velocity $h'(t)$ is an element of $T_{h(t)}M$, so we can interpret $h'$ as a section of $TM$ restricted to $\gamma$, and the problem can be generalized as follows: given a vector bundle $E\to M$, restrict it to a submanifold $Z\subset M$, and consider a section $\sigma:Z\to E_{\restriction Z}$. Can we always extend it to a neghbourhood of $Z$?

You should be able to find an answer in these related questions:

[Extension of Sections of Restricted Vector Bundles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213987/261022)

[Proving The Extension Lemma For Vector Fields On Submanifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247240/261022)

Let me know if you find this helpful, or if you'd like me to provide more details.